# How can I locate an XCUIElement searching by partial label text in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, automation, xctest, xcuitest

I have been locating XCUIElements using this method:

```
app.staticTexts["Full Label Text"]
```

But what if I only know part of the label text? Part of the label text is generated dynamically (e.g. "Item #1", "Item #2", etc.) so I would like to search for it by finding an element that contains part of the text (e.g. searching by "Item"). Is there any method to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can find elements with a predicate. Use the `containing(_ predicate: NSPredicate) -> XCUIElementQuery` method from `XCUIElementQuery`.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS[c] 'Item'")
let labels = XCUIApplication().staticTexts.containing(predicate)
```

Comment: What is the `[c]` for?

Comment: Case insensitivity. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB

Comment: Please see this gist for an example of how to use this in order to click on photos in the Camera Roll: https://gist.github.com/bitops/9182b5ee96c682aba57d9fa16ca6b987

Comment: `let labels = XCUIApplication().staticTexts.matching(predicate)` may I know the different between `containing` and `matching` usage here?

Answer (score 1):

**The accepted answer only seems to work if you DO NOT set an accessibilityLabel in which case you might want to use                     .accessibilityIdentifier instead**

I also ran into this issue and wasn't getting the expected results beacuse I was using `accessibilityLabel` and not `accessibilityIdentifier` .

Here is the UI,

[image: DemoView showing the 5 UI elements]

Here is the output of the test case code,

```
Element Info - Type: Window     Label:                                          Value: 
Element Info - Type: StaticText Label: Hello World with No Acccessibility Label Value: 
Element Info - Type: StaticText Label: AcccessibilityLabel                      Value: 
Element Info - Type: TextField  Label: TextFieldSwiftUI                         Value: Initial Text
Element Info - Type: Button     Label: Click Me!                                Value:
```

Here is the code,

1. DemoView

   ```
   struct DemoView: View {

       @State
       var textEntry = "Initial Text"

       var body: some View{
           Text("Hello World with No Acccessibility Label")
               .font(.largeTitle)
                .accessibilityIdentifier("AcccessibilityID")
               .padding()
           Text("Hello World with an Acccessibility Label")
               .font(.largeTitle)
               .accessibilityLabel("AcccessibilityLabel")
               .padding()

           TextField("Title", text: $textEntry)
               .accessibilityLabel("TextFieldSwiftUI")
               .padding()

           Button("Click Me!") {
               print("Clicked")
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. DemoViewUITests

   ```
   class DemoViewUITests: XCTestCase {

       override func setUpWithError() throws {}
       override func tearDownWithError() throws {}
       func testExample() throws {
           // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
           let app = XCUIApplication()
           app.launch()

           // get all the elements in the app
           let allTheElements = app.descendants(matching: .any)

           // filter out the 'other' elements
           // These seem to be the internal views wrapping the app
           // as they all have a frame of the full window
           // looking at the Window Inspector I think they are
           // - UITransitionView
           // - UIDropShadowView
           // - HostingViewController
           // - HostingView
           let notOtherPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "elementType != %d",
                                               // can't just use the enum value
                                               // see stackoverflow.com/questions/32298645/enum-value-and-predicates
                                               // so we pass in the NSUInteger version (other is 1)
                                               // see developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes/1500614-elementtype
                                               argumentArray: [XCUIElement.ElementType.other.rawValue])
           let elements = allTheElements.matching(notOtherPredicate)

           // should have 5
           // 1 - the Window
           // 2 - the Text with no accessibility label
           // 3 - the Text with an accessibility label
           // 4 - the TextField
           // 5 - the Button
           XCTAssertEqual(elements.count, 5)

           for elementIndex in 0..<elements.count{
               let element     = elements.element(boundBy: elementIndex)
               let type  = ELEMENT_TYPE[element.elementType.rawValue]!.padding(toLength: 10, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
               let label = "\(element.label)".padding(toLength: 40, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
               let value = "\(element.value ?? "NIL")"
               print("Element Info - Type: \(type) Label: \(label) Value: \(value)")
           }

       }
   }

   // Rest is just for pretty formatting :)
   // can't extract key representation
   // from C Struct XCUIElementType
   // (even though it's XCUIElement.ElementType it
   // points to XCUIElementType weird...)
   // so we provide a table here
   var ELEMENT_TYPE : [UInt: String] = [
       0 : "Any",
       1 : "Other",
       2 : "Application",
       3 : "Group",
       4 : "Window",
       5 : "Sheet",
       6 : "Drawer",
       7 : "Alert",
       8 : "Dialog",
       9 : "Button",
       10 : "RadioButton",
       11 : "RadioGroup",
       12 : "CheckBox",
       13 : "DisclosureTriangle",
       14 : "PopUpButton",
       15 : "ComboBox",
       16 : "MenuButton",
       17 : "ToolbarButton",
       18 : "Popover",
       19 : "Keyboard",
       20 : "Key",
       21 : "NavigationBar",
       22 : "TabBar",
       23 : "TabGroup",
       24 : "Toolbar",
       25 : "StatusBar",
       26 : "Table",
       27 : "TableRow",
       28 : "TableColumn",
       29 : "Outline",
       30 : "OutlineRow",
       31 : "Browser",
       32 : "CollectionView",
       33 : "Slider",
       34 : "PageIndicator",
       35 : "ProgressIndicator",
       36 : "ActivityIndicator",
       37 : "SegmentedControl",
       38 : "Picker",
       39 : "PickerWheel",
       40 : "Switch",
       41 : "Toggle",
       42 : "Link",
       43 : "Image",
       44 : "Icon",
       45 : "SearchField",
       46 : "ScrollView",
       47 : "ScrollBar",
       48 : "StaticText",
       49 : "TextField",
       50 : "SecureTextField",
       51 : "DatePicker",
       52 : "TextView",
       53 : "Menu",
       54 : "MenuItem",
       55 : "MenuBar",
       56 : "MenuBarItem",
       57 : "Map",
       58 : "WebView",
       59 : "IncrementArrow",
       60 : "DecrementArrow",
       61 : "Timeline",
       62 : "RatingIndicator",
       63 : "ValueIndicator",
       64 : "SplitGroup",
       65 : "Splitter",
       66 : "RelevanceIndicator",
       67 : "ColorWell",
       68 : "HelpTag",
       69 : "Matte",
       70 : "DockItem",
       71 : "Ruler",
       72 : "RulerMarker",
       73 : "Grid",
       74 : "LevelIndicator",
       75 : "Cell",
       76 : "LayoutArea",
       77 : "LayoutItem",
       78 : "Handle",
       79 : "Stepper",
       80 : "Tab",
       81 : "TouchBar",
       82 : "StatusItem",
   ]
   ```